# sql [db2] select statement with condition

Tags: sql, select, db2

I have two tables.
player1 has rows username, score, game_id, ...
player2 has rows username, score, game_id...
how do you select the username with the biggest score for the same game_id?

what I have is

```
SELECT player1.username winning,
  player1.points,
  player1.game_id 
FROM player1 
INNER JOIN player2 ON player1.game_id = player2.game_id
WHERE player1.points > player2.points
```

and

```
SELECT player2.username winning,
  player2.points,
  player2.game_id 
FROM player1 
INNER JOIN player2 ON player1.game_id = player2.game_id
WHERE player2.points > player1.points
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it:

```
SELECT
    game_id, 
    CASE WHEN p1.score > p2.score THEN p1.username ELSE p2.username END AS winner
FROM
    player1 p1
INNER JOIN
    player2 p2 ON p1.game_id = p2.game_id
ORDER BY 
    p1.game_id ASC
```

As Darius mentioned, you may wish to adjust the CASE statement according to the situation of a Draw, you may change it to something like this:

```
CASE WHEN p1.score > p2.score THEN p1.username WHEN p1.score < p2.score THEN p2.username ELSE 'Draw' END AS winner
```

It really depends on what you want to display in that scenario.

Comment: And you might also refine the CASE expression so that if the scores are equal, you return something to tell you so